# How to send a text alert message to particular group of people when user clikc on send button using powerapps and excel

Tags: excel, user-interface, alert, message, powerapps

I have created a excel with group of people and I have made them into 2 grps using another column and I have created a ui in power apps when user selects one of the group that particular grp members should get the text message

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

**1. Use `Launch("SMS:" & lblSelectedGroup.Text & "&body=Hi")` for the `OnSelect` Property of a button control**

- Only usable on mobile devices with SMS texting capabilities

**2. Use the SMS connector in Power Automate**

- Send the phone number and message parameters from PowerApps to Power Automate
- Power Automate sends the SMS text

**3. Use a 3rd party connector**

- Twilio
- TxtSync
- Etc.